# How are the .exe files in Scripts folder for python generated?

Tags: python, scripting, exe

I noticed that in Scripts folder inside the python installation folder there are executable files. Each file about a 100kb in size.

FYI: when I open it (or them) using 7Zip I often find a **init**.py file inside.

Answer (score 3):

The `setuptools` package builder is able to

> Automatically generate wrapper scripts or Windows (console and GUI) .exe files for any number of “main” functions in your project. (Note: this is not a py2exe replacement; the .exe files rely on the local Python installation.)

([ref.](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) from setuptools documentation)

Unfortunately the way it is actually done is considered an *implementation detail* and is not documented.

Comment: That's brightens up most of the dark parts. Though I really wanted the implementation. But, I guess it can't be helped